# How to get rid of # in answer (eigensystem)?

Tags: matrix, linear-algebra

I was trying to find the eigensystem of the following matrix (act as if the second character is in subscript):

\begin{pmatrix}
 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
 \frac{-\text{c1}-\text{c3}}{\text{mn}} &
   \frac{\text{c3}}{\text{mn}} &
   \frac{-\text{c2}-\text{c4}}{\text{mn}} &
   \frac{\text{c4}}{\text{mn}} \\
 \frac{\text{c3}}{\text{mc}} & -\frac{\text{c3}}{\text{mc}} &
   \frac{\text{c4}}{\text{mc}} & -\frac{\text{c4}}{\text{mc}} \\
\end{pmatrix}

However, it returns a lot of # in the answer. I have looked up the documentation, but I haven't a clue about how to get from the answer mathematica gives to the actual eigenvectors. (I got the eigenvalues by hand eventually, but I'm having trouble to get the vectors). Also, I find that it doesn't really matter if I substitute values for the constants, it will still give me a weird answer that I don't understand.

Does anyone know how to solve this?

Comment: @SjoerdC.deVries I found that the linked question only recieved answers for that particular problem rather than the problem in general

Comment: Check the links in its comments

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Eigenvalues are represented as Roots of a polynomial equation which is in turn expressed using the #'s. This is normal and correct.

If you enter numbers for the parameters of your matrix and apply N[] to your Eigenvalues the #'s will vanish.